# Get rows with subset of numbers from SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have SQL database table and I am trying to return rows where a column starts with 8 specific numbers. For example we can call the column "numbers", which will always have 11 numbers. I am looking to return rows where the first 8 are "24681234". I have tried to use the "LIKE" command, but it takes FOREVER to run, considering the size of the database. Here is the command I'm using at the moment:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CREATE_TIME, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, NUMBER, SN
FROM MY_TABLE WHERE NUMBER LIKE '35722806%' OR NUMBER LIKE '35981106%'
```

Is there a quicker way to search for this info?

Comment: Have you considered creating an index on `NUMBER` and `IMEI`? And how big is the table (row count & size)?

Comment: Is the column 'numbers' defined as a column of numeric datatype or as string datatype?

Comment: @ZoffDino I'm trying to get the count right now, but I'm going to assume it's large considering it's been running the count query for a few minutes. I'm guessing I'll have to index this, then run the query to speed things up.

Comment: Use `EXEC sp_spaceused 'MY_TABLE'` for a quick count

Comment: @ZoffDino, thanks. There are ~14,000,000  rows... So yeah, pretty big. How long would it take to index that?

Comment: That greatly depends on your CPU, RAM, etc. but it shouldn't matter. Create the index is a one time operation. You will pay a small price with each INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE the trade-off is much faster SELECT time.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possible options for you:-

```
SELECT TOP 1 CREATE_TIME, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, NUMBER, SN FROM MY_TABLE WHERE LEFT(NUMBER,8) ='35722806' OR LEFT(IMEI,8) ='35981106'
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 1 CREATE_TIME, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, NUMBER, SN FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SUBSTRING(NUMBER,0,9) ='35722806' OR SUBSTRING(IMEI,0,9) = '35981106'
```

Perhaps creating an index on the columns would help also.

Comment: These queries aren't [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). So if there's an index on the relevant column(s), the original query is likely to perform much better.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the column 'numbers' is of numeric datatype you can

```
SELECT TOP 1 CREATE_TIME, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, NUMBER, SN 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE 
   NUMBER BETWEEN 35722806000 AND 35722806999 
   OR IMEI BEWEEN 35981106000 AND 35981106999
```

Having an index on this field will help selecting, but performance for many inserts are a trade off.